# Javascript access array index using integer array

Tags: arrays

I have an array like this:

`var rndArray = [0,0,0,0]`

and another array like this:

`var array= [[[[['DONE']]]]]`

What I want is to access the 'DONE' value using rndArray, like:

```
array[0][0][0][0]
```

How can I get it using rndArray in this case?

Comment: What you're looking for is called _lenses_ and is a concept from functional programming. Just accessing can be done with loops or `.reduce` like Ron proposed. But if you would want _altering_ values, it's best to see into some libraries implementing _lenses_ for JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

using reduce

```js
rndArray.reduce((acc, curr) => acc[curr], array)[0]
```

Comment: I oversimplified it, I really need a solution for cases, where 'DONE' is hidden in a different index, e.g. when rndArray = [1,3,5,11] and value is actually hidden in this index order.

Comment: Can you give an example?, I not sure I understand the case

Comment: in such case,  var array = [
    [n],
    [y, [n],
        [n],
        [y, [n],
            [n],
            [n],
            [n],
            [y, [n],
                [n],
                [n],
                [n],
                [n],
                [n],
                [n],
                [n],
                [n],
                [n],
                ["Done"]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]